# Normal $n$-distribution and Variance-covariance matrix

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

The following is from my lecture:

=======================================start

Let $x$ be a standard normal vector of length $n$.

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ be a matrix.

Then we say that $Ax$ has normal distributed components.
Or we could say that $Ax$ is a vector whose components are normally distributed with length $m$.

Example:

$$
A =
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & -2 \\
2 & 1  \\
\end{bmatrix}
\\
x =^{(d)} N(O, I_{2\times 2}) = \begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y \\
\end{bmatrix}
\\
Ax = \begin{bmatrix}
3X - 2Y \\
2X + Y \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$3X - 2Y =^{(d)}N(0,3^2+2^2) = N(0,13)\\
2X + Y =^{(d)} N(0, 4^2+1) = N(0,5)
$$

=====================================end

My question is, what exactly is matrix A, and if somebody can explain the example above. How do we get to Variance covariance matrix from the above and what does it tell us?

Answer (score 1):

We usually say that $Ax$ is a Gaussian vector of length $n$, that is, for each $c_1,\dots,c_n\in\mathbb R$, denoting $Y_j$ the $j$-th component of $Ax$, the random variable $\sum_{j=1}^nc_j Y_j$ has a Gaussian (possibly degenerated) distribution.

We usually specify the vector of means of each component and the covariance matrix, whose $(i,j)$ entry is $\operatorname{Cov}(Y_i,Y_j)$.

Comment: Can you help me see this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4500939/can-we-take-the-coupling-of-mu-and-nu? Thank you!